# Laravel Nova: enable/disable actions log view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Laravel Nova keeps a log of actions, and can show it like any other resource.

For one of my projects this is somehow enabled, while for a different project (same Nova version) I don't see the `Actions` under my resources. I'm not sure why.

So how does one enable or disable this view?

Comment: Have you checked following docs - https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/actions/defining-actions.html#action-log

Answer (score 1):

Need add trait `Actionable` to models for enable Action Log.

```php
use Laravel\Nova\Actions\Actionable;
```

```php
    use Actionable;
```